# How to test if method has been called only once and not the second time in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, knockout.js, jasmine

I am testing mechanism that should call method once and prevent any subsequent calls with jasmine, I can see by attaching breakpoints that method is NOT being called second time however jasmine test fails. I would assume it has to do with `spy` not being designed to be used for multiple checks.
**What would be proper solution to given situation?**

[JSfiddle of Code that is being tested](http://jsfiddle.net/wzAyL/124/) I could not figure out how to do jasmine test jsfiddle properly (Jasmine version I am using is 1.3.1 while test template is on 1.2.0).

Test looks like this:

```
 it("Invoking OnPreQuery will add event listener for OnTheMoveViewPreLoad event. Triggering OnTheMoveViewPreLoad twice will call getChildrenForMasterRecordList only first time", function () {
            AddTreeSettingsObjectToBC({ bc: bc, Tree: { IncludeChildren: true} });
            ComposeMockPageObjWithObservableFieldsWithChildren();
            var preQuerySpy = spyOnEvent(onTheMove.PageDataRoles, 'OnPreQuery');
            $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).trigger('OnPreQuery', { knockoutContextName: 'bc' });
            expect('OnPreQuery').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(onTheMove.PageDataRoles);
            expect(preQuerySpy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
            var getChildrenForMasterRecordListSpy = spyOn(window, 'getChildrenForMasterRecordList');
            $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).trigger('OnTheMoveViewPreLoad', { knockoutContextName: 'bc' });
            expect(getChildrenForMasterRecordListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).trigger('OnTheMoveViewPreLoad', { knockoutContextName: 'bc' });
            expect(getChildrenForMasterRecordListSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

Code that is being tested: 
HTML

```
<div data-role="page"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var onTheMove = function(){};
$.extend(onTheMove,{
    NullValue : "null",
    PageDataRoles : 'div[data-role="page"], div[data-role="dialog"]',
    OnTheMovePrefix : 'OnTheMove_'
    });

$(document).on('OnPreQuery', onTheMove.PageDataRoles, function (e, options) {
    var isChildAttachmentQueued = true;
    var knockoutContextName = options.knockoutContextName;
    if (TreeEnabled(knockoutContextName)) {
        var isModelReadyToAttachChildren = function () {
            var isReady = false;
            if (PageObj[knockoutContextName] != undefined) {
                isReady = (PageObj[knockoutContextName]().length > 0) && isChildAttachmentQueued;
            }

            return isReady;
        };
        var treeSettings = eval(knockoutContextName).Tree;
        treeSettings.knockoutContextName = knockoutContextName;
        $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).on('OnTheMoveViewPreLoad', function (e, options) {
            if (isModelReadyToAttachChildren()) {
                getChildrenForMasterRecordList({
                    parentTable: eval(knockoutContextName).primaryTableName,
                    knockoutContextName: treeSettings.knockoutContextName,
                    parentIdColumn: treeSettings.ParentIdColumn,
                    masterIdColumn: treeSettings.MasterIdColumn
                });
                isChildAttachmentQueued = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
function getChildrenForMasterRecordList(options) {
    console.log('beep');
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)**

now makes this much easier.

```
 expect(yourSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I also find out the arguments which were used for each call?

Comment: Certainly. Try `.toHaveBeenCalledWith("yourArgument")`

Comment: sorry, I am confused. If a spy was called two times with argument 1 for first call and 2 for 2nd, how can i check that  (a) spy was called two times (b) 1st call was with argument 1 (c) 2nd call was with argument 2?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your function, you may want to check them separately. That way if it fails, you know exactly why. Something like this:

1. Check that your function was called twice, using `.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` 
2. Check that your function was called with argument 1, using `toHaveBeenCalledWith("argument 1")`
3. Check that your function was called with argument 2, using `toHaveBeenCalledWith("argument 2")`

If you are wanting to check the _order_, that may be a little trickier. You may be able to dig into the spy object and check the array position of each call.

Answer (score 32):

Figured it out myself, spy has property `callCount` that auto-increments by one on each call.

```
    it("Invoking OnPreQuery will add event listener for OnTheMoveViewPreLoad event. Triggering OnTheMoveViewPreLoad twice will call getChildrenForMasterRecordList only first time", function () {
        AddTreeSettingsObjectToBC({ bc: bc, Tree: { IncludeChildren: true} });
        ComposeMockPageObjWithObservableFieldsWithChildren();
        var preQuerySpy = spyOnEvent(onTheMove.PageDataRoles, 'OnPreQuery');
        $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).trigger('OnPreQuery', { knockoutContextName: 'bc' });
        expect('OnPreQuery').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(onTheMove.PageDataRoles);
        expect(preQuerySpy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
        var getChildrenForMasterRecordListSpy = spyOn(window, 'getChildrenForMasterRecordList');
        $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).trigger('OnTheMoveViewPreLoad', { knockoutContextName: 'bc' });
        expect(getChildrenForMasterRecordListSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).trigger('OnTheMoveViewPreLoad', { knockoutContextName: 'bc' });
        expect(getChildrenForMasterRecordListSpy.callCount).toEqual(1);
    });
```

**as per comment**

in Jasmine 2.0 its

```
expect(object.func.calls.count()).toBe(1);
```

Comment: In jasmine 2.0, this has changed slightly. You now checks calls.count()... for instance: expect(object.func.calls.count()).toBe(1);